# Livestream in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, stream, web-audio-api, icecast

I am trying to play an IceCast stream (MP3 streaming over HTTP) via the Web Audio API (not an `audio` tag), support for recent browsers except IE is an unfortunate requirement.

All examples and projects I can find regarding this either use a `XMLHttpRequest` to load a whole file (which won't work because the request will never be finished), or stream live user input (microphone) via `createMediaStreamSource`.

How can I use the Web Audio API to create a sourceNode from a stream?

Here's a demo showing that indeed XMLHttpRequest can not be used to load binary streams: http://codepen.io/rrorg/pen/EyAmBa?editors=1010

Comment: @guest271314 different topic, I am trying to find a solution not using `audio` tags and delays are not a problem

Comment: You can substitute Web Audio API for `<audio>` tag and use same pattern at duplicate Question

Comment: Let me repeat: I am trying to find a solution not using audio tags and delays are not a problem

Comment: Yes, you can use `ReadableStream` returned by `response.body` of `fetch()` to update audio context.

Comment: `fetch` seems like a good solution, but the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) is just not there yet :(

Comment: `fetch` appears to be supported at same browsers Web Audio API is supported, save for safari http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Comment: You could also use `XMLHttpRequest`, `FileReader` to recursively append `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` of stream to audio context,  until end of stream.

Comment: Safari is my main concern in this, yes. Is there a way in `XMLHttpRequest` to get the blob data before the `onload` event? This will never fire since the stream is basically an "infinite" download.

Comment: _"Safari is my main concern in this, yes. Is there a way in XMLHttpRequest to get the blob data before the onload event? This will never fire since the stream is basically an "infinite" download."_ Can you update Question to include these details, `html`, current `javascript` tried to solve issue? You should be able to append `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` to stream continuously

Comment: What code would be helpful in this case? XMLHttpRequest will simply not give you the raw data before the request is finished, unless you're streaming text.

Comment: You can set `XMLHttpRequest.responseType` to `"blob"` or `"arraybuffer"`. At `load` event of request, append chunk of binary data from response to stream by appending `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob` of binary data to existing streaming `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob URL` at audio context. Can you include the `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120884/discussion-between-rene-roth-and-guest271314).

Comment: I have made a [demo](http://codepen.io/rrorg/pen/EyAmBa?editors=1010) showing that no load event will be triggered for a stream.

Comment: Is requirement to not use `fetch()`?

Comment: as answered before, I need Safari support :(

Comment: _"as answered before, I need Safari support :( "_ should be included at Question as requirement? With links to safari support for `fetch()`?

Comment: I edited it into the question to make you happy. The StackOverflow comment box explicitly states "use comments to ask for more information" - which is what you did and you got your answer. Please stop derailing this discussion. If you feel the need to adjust the initial question, you're free to use the appropriate StackOverflow edit function.

Comment: Have you tried using `new Audio()`?

Comment: `new Audio()` is exactly the same as creating an `<audio>` tag, unfortunately.

Comment: What is expected output `AudioNode` of audio stream? `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` itself is an `AudioNode` . Why cannot an `AudioNode` be created and utilized using `new Audio()`? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode

Comment: Are you trying to play audio without using an `AudioNode`? _"The AudioContext interface represents an audio-processing graph built from audio modules linked together, each represented by an [`AudioNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode). "_ See [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a normal audio node?

Comment: @RenéRoth _"XMLHttpRequest will simply not give you the raw data before the request is finished, unless you're streaming text."_ Was able to retrieve binary string of `.responseText` of `XMLHttpRequest()` to second link at codepen http://codepen.io/rrorg/pen/EyAmBa?editors=1010, and convert to an `ArrayBuffer`, though `.decodeAudioData()` is logging error `DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`

Comment: Would it be possible to use `<audio>` or `new Audio()` in combination with `createMediaElementSource`? (The only reason I can think of for not using `audio` is an older Safari bug with that function). Anyway, if you set `crossorigin="anonymous"` on the `audio` element, this should [works just fine](http://jsbin.com/towevihuso/1/edit).

Comment: @Brad - I would imagine the reason is that OP didn't want to use <audio> is that it doesn't support Icecast metadata, as that's the reason I'm researching this topic now.  It looks like there isn't a useful current way to get icecast metadata in an HTML5 context without a custom server (i.e. separating the metadata from the audio stream and providing the former via a websocket interface).

Comment: @Brad I'd appreciate a theoretical technical write up, which should not hinder your chances of making a sale, I assume :)